# how to extract data using a single value?

Tags: r, dplyr, extract

Can anyone please help to guide me on how to convert the table into a table that only contains data for participants taking ABC?

```
library(tibble)

data <- tibble(ID = 1:3,
                 `meds A` = c("ABC", "XYZ", "QWE"),
                 `visit 1` = c(1, 2, 1),
                 `day 1` = c(50, 30 , 20),
                 `meds B` = c("QWE", "XYZ", "ABC"),
                 `visit 2` = c(4, 5, 1),
                 `day 2` = c(77, 90, 25))

abc_data <- data %>%
  filter(`meds A` == "ABC") %>%
  select(ID, visit_1, day_1) %>%
  rename(visit = visit_1, day = day_1)
```

But then I could not get meds B "ABC"...

Comment: Hi @Jia Wei Tan--welcome to SO! In order to help we'll need you to provide more info. Please see how to do so at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: specifically, can you provide `dput()` of your `abc_data`?

Comment: Already tried `subset(dat, medsA == 'ABC')`?

Comment: Try `data %>% filter(rowSums(across(starts_with("meds"), \(x) x == "ABC")) > 0)`

Comment: Hi Jia Wei! Welcome to StackOverflow. I added a reproducible input based on your screenshot. There was a slight discrepancy between your code, which had underscores in the column names, and the screenshot, which did not. If indeed it did have underscores, lmk or edit it yourself :-)

Comment: @RKeithL I transcribed the screenshot :-)

Comment: @AndreWildberg I transcribed the screenshot, if you wanted to post that as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Andre's comment solution works, but I would suggest making the data long, as your data is [untidy](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html), and storing information in column names (e.g. day number) is bad practice.

I *think* I understand the structure of the data - `meds A`, `visit 1`, and `day 1` are one group of variables, and the next three are another group (?) - correct me if I'm wrong!

In this case, using `pivot_longer()` to make the data long, then filtering for any ID with a medication which is `ABC` is the way to go (shown below):

```
library(dplyr)

data |>
  rename(`meds 1` = `meds A`, `meds 2` = `meds B`) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = c(".value", 'n'), names_sep = " ") |> 
  filter(any(meds == "ABC"), .by = ID)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
     ID n     meds  visit   day
  <int> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 1     ABC       1    50
2     1 2     QWE       4    77
3     3 1     QWE       1    20
4     3 2     ABC       1    25
```